# Can't Vectorize Loop

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, hpc

In my c++ program I have a code snippet which evaluates the cost of a path inside a graph. It works perfectly fine but, since it's called a fairly amount of time, I'd like the loop that computes it to be vectorized by the compiler.

The snippet is the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    int n = 10;

    int** graph = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            graph[i] = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            graph[i][i] = 0;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
                int w = (rand() % 99) + 2;
                graph[i][j] = w;
                graph[j][i] = w;
            }
        }

    std::vector<int> path(n);
    std::iota(path.begin(), path.end(), 0);

    int length = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; i++){
        int to = path[i];
        int from = path[i + 1];
        int l = graph[to][from];
        length += l;
    }
    std::cout << length << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately when I compile with `g++ -O3 -fopt-info-vec-missed` flags I get the infamous `missed: couldn't vectorize loop`

```
test.cpp:27:22: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cpp:30:25: missed: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _27 = *_26;
test.cpp:15:34: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cpp:15:34: missed: not vectorized: inner-loop count not invariant.
test.cpp:15:34: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cpp:16:30: missed: statement clobbers memory: _11 = rand ();
test.cpp:10:27: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cpp:11:33: missed: statement clobbers memory: _45 = operator new [] (40);
test.cpp:9:29: missed: statement clobbers memory: _43 = operator new [] (80);
test.cpp:11:33: missed: statement clobbers memory: _45 = operator new [] (40);
test.cpp:16:30: missed: statement clobbers memory: _11 = rand ();
test.cpp:33:18: missed: not vectorized: statement can throw an exception: _61 = std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<< (&cout, length_97);
```

How can I have the path evaluation loop vectorized?

Comment: what infamous compiler are you using?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the complete compiler message

Comment: `-ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1` (assuming g++)

Comment: @ChrisMM I used those flags but the output is the same. I just posted all of it

Comment: @idclev463035818 the infamous g++. I just divided it in two blocks cause I thought it looked better but, apart from `int main()` and the includes, that's basically it. Should I merge the block and add the rest?

Comment: those numbers in the compiler message refer to line numbers in your original code, having to re-add the includes can be cumbersome and the presence of `using namespace std;` can have consequences (I hope you are `using std::vetor` etc but currently I cannot know), so yes, it would help to reproduce the exact same message as you get

Comment: is this really the code for that compiler output? It mentions some `ostream::operator<<`, which is a bit odd, because there is no `operator<<` in the code

Comment: do you include the header for `rand` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 sorry I just uploaded the full code. I had just omitted a cout at the end cause I though there was no way it was its fault. It appears it was

Comment: doesnt change the answer substantially. The `cout` is outside of the loop

Comment: "I had just omitted a cout at the end cause I though there was no way it was its fault"  Details do matter. Always. Don't assume you know where the problem is not, because if you knew where the problem is you wouldn't need to ask ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 yep you are right :) Though, I still don't understand how does that `cout` prevent the loop from vectorizing? And what should I do if I want to print the result and have the loop vectorized?

Comment: why do you think that cout prevents loop vectorization? It doesn say "couldn't vectorize loop" for the loop you care about

Comment: @idclev463035818 Actually it does, look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/SSbt-Y)

Comment: where do you read that the loop in line 26 was not vectorized? I dont see it

Comment: your interpreation is wrong. You also get a warning for the `cout` when there is no loop at all: https://godbolt.org/z/YENkhR

Comment: First line of the compiler output is `<source>:26:22: missed: couldn't vectorize loop` and that's the loop I need to vectorize. What do you mean? In the link you sent it says `missed statement`, not `couldn't vectorize loop`

Comment: what I mean is that I missed that line of the message partly because the code I based my answer on is a different one

Comment: fwiw, the `cout` makes the difference because without it you arent using any result of the loop and it can be optimized away

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! So, basically vectorization happens as long as I don't use the computed results? It seems kinda useless...

Comment: no if you don't use the result then the loop is removed by the compiler (as-if rule, you cannot tell the difference)

Comment: Then, what's the problem with vectorizing that loop?